# Is it available to use feedback function in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm beginner in Octave. I'm sorry if I ask a silly question.

I want to use [feedback function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/control/function/@lti/feedback.html) in Control package.
I installed this package, using following command.

`pkg install -forge control`

The Installation seems to be successful, and following directory is automatically generated.

```
~/octave/control-2.6.5
```

But Octave says following messages when I enter "feedback" in Octave.

```
warning: the 'feedback' function belongs to the control package from Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.
```

"feedback.m" file exists in "~/octave/control-2.6.5/@lti".
How do I use this .m file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Octave version: 3.8.1

Comment: see the [package documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/control/overview.html) which lists all of its functions.

Comment: on Octave version 5.1.0 this is still the case, but it seems you _can use_ `feedback`, just, at the CLI, `help feedback` is weird, as is simply typing `feedback`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load it before you can use it. Just execute

```
 pkg load control
```

on the octave prompt.

**Edit:**

After this you can do:

```
s1 = tf (1, [1 2]);
s2 = tf (1, [1 5]);
cl = feedback (s1, s2)
```

which outputs:

```
Transfer function 'cl' from input 'u1' to output ...

          s + 5     
 y1:  --------------
      s^2 + 7 s + 11
```

Use bode and step to evaluate the result. If you want help type `help @lti/feedback` on the octave prompt.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. According to your advice, I executed the command with no error message. However "feedback" function isn't available in my environment. Do I make a mistake or forget something?

Comment: I confirm that the answer works fine on octave 3.8.1, with the same output, and no warning. What is strange is maybe that `which feedback` returns nothing. And `help feedback` yields `error: help: the 'feedback' function belongs to the control package from Octave
Forge but has not yet been implemented.`. Sounds like a bug. The `help @lti/feedback` mentioned in Andy's answer works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.You're right. It works as I expected.